# Rails help to validate number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to validate a form that gets submitted. The name of the param that is send is ratings. And that param gets saved in the rating_score column.

I want to validate that the param ratings is only between 1 and 5.

I have put this in my model:
validates_inclusion_of :rating_score, :in => 1..5

After that I submitted my form with the param ratings = 6 and it got saved in my database.

My controller:

```
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrancer.rating_score ||= 0
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@konkurrancer.id.to_s
    @konkurrancer.rating_score += params[:vind][:ratings].to_i
    @konkurrancer.ratings += 1
    @konkurrancer.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :rating_score
validates_inclusion_of :rating_score, :in => 1..5
end
```

My log when submitting my form:

```
Started POST "/konkurrancers/rate/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-03 23:23:53 +0200
  Processing by KonkurrancersController#rate as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"h6RSZbuVVfYIvdNb31xS6Oo7Q8o
1JxvVL24aoJ2GQ/o=", "vind"=>{"ratings"=>"6"}, "id"=>"7"}

Completed 200 OK in 488ms (Views: 239.0ms | ActiveRecord: 20.0ms)
```

How to do the validation?

Comment: show your controller code (and model as well)

Comment: which rails version do you use?

Comment: Are you sure rating_score an integer? Can you show us the migration of that field?

Comment: The ratings param gets submitted with a text field

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up the number of ratings with the rating score? Does this represent (params[:vind][:ratings].to_i) rating score?

Comment: you are validating wrong attribute

Comment: What just happen all my accounts got merged to one ?

Comment: @Rails - you said you had a few accounts, so I merged them together for you. Have you considered registering an account?

Comment: Yes thanks that was awesome. I will register an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save it before render view. Looks like your object is not saved, but your `rating_score` is dirty and equal 6.

```
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrancer.rating_score ||= 0
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@konkurrancer.id.to_s
    @konkurrancer.rating_score += params[:vind][:ratings].to_i
    @konkurrancer.ratings += 1
    if @konkurrancer.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**OLD**

Ok you are validating `rating_score` but not `raitings`

So if you set `ratings = 6` it will saved.

But if you will set `rating_score = 6` it won't be saved, because your validation is right.

Try this

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rating_score
  validates_inclusion_of :rating_score, :in => 1..5
end
```

or

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rating_score
  validates :rating_score, :inclusion => { :in => 1..5 }
end
```

Comment: I have tried both ratings and rating_score without any result it still gets saved

Comment: Is `ratings` a column in your database? Are you sure you've putted all your model code?

Comment: Yes but the param ratings gets saved as rating_score I have updated my question with my rails log

Comment: so what does this mean: `@konkurrancer.ratings += 1`

Comment: It adds 1 to count the number of ratings

Comment: haha ) why do you use `ratings` param to set `rating_score` while you have got the same attribute name... so messy.

Comment: Yes totally sure I have looked in my database. Should the validation be something with validating  ratings_attribute instead of just ratings?

Comment: I second the question, is it saved? Check the database. you are not checking the return value of the save call, so you don't even know in your code whether it succeeded or not.  Usually you should do a "if save, redirect, else render form with errors" pattern.

Comment: In your case it should be `rating_score` :)

Comment: I want to validate the ratings attribute that gets saved in the rating_score column

Comment: validates :rating_score, :inclusion => { :in => 1..5 }

Answer (score 1):

try to use validates_numericality_of

```
validates_numericality_of :ratings , :less_than_or_equal_to=>5, :greater_than_or_equal_to=>1
```

Comment: I have tried it dosent work. I have updated my question with my rails log of the form submit